# JWplayer error ‘Video not found or access denied’

Tags: jquery

I am running an intranet with no internet access.  Using Server2003 IIS6, I cannot get jwplayer or any player, to show files when run from the IIS server.  I continually get an ‘Video not found or access denied’ error.  It works fine when web page is run locally on any computer, just not from the server. I’ve checked the mime settings and the path is ok. Help!!

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because JWPlayer trying to connect their CDN to check your key (`jwplayer.key=`) and it won't load in your local network, unless if the device you trying to play has internet access.